# Modifying of the Mwe2 workflow generated by Xtext programmatically

Tags: java, dsl, xtext

I'm running Mwe2 workflow programmatically and I need to add referencedResource for the Terminals.xtext to the GenerateYourDsl.mwe2 file in order to run this workflow successfully. Mentioned GenerateYourDsl.mwe2 file is generated by Xtext when I create new project - I didn't modify it. 
Is it somehow possible to get object out of this workflow, access it in Java and add this one attribute to the language attribute of the component attribute of the workflow ?

Here's the workflow:

```
Workflow {

    component = XtextGenerator {
        configuration = {
            project = StandardProjectConfig {
                baseName = "org.example.yourdsl"
                rootPath = rootPath
                eclipsePlugin = {
                    enabled = true
                }
                createEclipseMetaData = true
            }
            code = {
                encoding = "UTF-8"
                lineDelimiter = "\n"
                fileHeader = "/*\n * generated by Xtext \${version}\n */"
            }
        }
        language = StandardLanguage {
            name = "org.example.yourdsl.YourDsl"
            fileExtensions = "yourdsl"
            //following line needs to be added - in original generated workflow it is not
           referencedResource = "platform:/resource/org.eclipse.xtext/org/eclipse/xtext/common/Terminals.xtext"

            serializer = {
                generateStub = false
            }
            validator = {
                // composedCheck = "org.eclipse.xtext.validation.NamesAreUniqueValidator"
                // Generates checks for @Deprecated grammar annotations, an IssueProvider and a corresponding PropertyPage
                generateDeprecationValidation = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm generating projects programmatically (using `CliProjectsCreator` and `WizardConfiguration`) and need to run the workflow when the projects are generated in order to generate src, src-gen files etc. But as I'm trying to run it programmatically (not in Eclipse) and Terminals are used in my grammar, I'm getting this error:

```
XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:1 Couldn't resolve reference to Grammar 'org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals'.
TransformationDiagnostic: null:36 Cannot create datatype WS. If this is supposed to return EString, make sure you have imported 'http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore' (ErrorCode: NoSuchTypeAvailable)
TransformationDiagnostic: null:39 Cannot create datatype NAME_TERMINAL. If this is supposed to return EString, make sure you have imported 'http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore' (ErrorCode: NoSuchTypeAvailable)
TransformationDiagnostic: null:42 Cannot create datatype VALUE_TERMINAL. If this is supposed to return EString, make sure you have imported 'http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore' (ErrorCode: NoSuchTypeAvailable)
```

Comment: why do you want to do that? terminals.xtext is available implicitely

Comment: It's not available implicitly when you're running the workflow programmatically - not in Eclipse.

Comment: can you give more details? maybe you do something strange classpath wise

Comment: I added it to the end of the description.

Comment: you should debug org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.XtextLinkingService.getUsedGrammar(Grammar, INode)
org.eclipse.xtext.resource.ClassloaderClasspathUriResolver.resolve(Object, URI)
what do you mean by "run programatically"

Comment: I mean `Mwe2Launcher launcher = new Mwe2Launcher(); launcher.run(new String[]{pathToMwe2File, "-p","rootPath=" + rootPath});`

Comment: how do you run this? how do you set class path. why dont you call 'org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main' as xtext gradle/maven do.

Comment: When I use org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main it produces the same result -> when above mentioned line (referencedResource) is not added to the workflow it exits with code 1, but when it's there everything's executed successfully.

Comment: Again how do you start this code. How do you populate the classpath. Did you debug the places I gave you

Comment: After debugging I see - there's an error 'Couldn't find resource on classpath. URI was 'classpath:/org/eclipse/xtext/common/Terminals.xtext' '. I didnt modify classpath at all. So probably I need to add Terminals.xtext to it. I'm running this code (Mwe2Launcher.main) via maven install in the phase of generating sources - firstly projects are generated, then this workflow is run. How can I modify classpath and add this dependency to it ?

Comment: As I still have no clue I cannot tell you. Maybe should should use Java exec plugin with stuff added to class path (have a look what new project wizard creates for maven)

Comment: Yes running `mvn exec:java@mwe2Launcher` works fine. Thanks a lot Christian!

Comment: You can write it as answer if you want, as by running that mvn action is no longer needed to change mwe2 workflow programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there should be no need to add the terminals grammar explicitely. It should be found on the classpath via `org.eclipse.xtext.resource.ClassloaderClasspathUriResolver.resolve(Object, URI)` if the workflow is called with a proper classpath.
have a look what the wizard creates when selecting maven: a call to the maven exec plugin calling into Mwe2Launcher main with the proper classpath